# Several actions were found that match request - webapi anonymous type+function

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm returning anonymouse type from my webapi controller, one of the values I need to be computed by using function. When I'm trying to do this way getting error say "Several actions were found that match request".
Here is how I call GET:

```
// GET api/Grafik/5
        public IHttpActionResult GetGrafik(int id)
        {
            xTourist t = db.xTourist.Find(id);
            var beach = db.xAdres.Find(t.Hotel).Kod;
            var result = from a in db.Grafik
                          join b in db.Excursions on a.Excursion equals b.Kod
                          join c in db.Dates on a.KodD equals c.KodD      
                          join d in db.Staff on a.Guide equals d.Kod
                         where c.Date > t.ArrDate && c.Дата < t.DepDate
                          let pu = from x in db.xPickUp where x.KodP == beach && x.Excursion == b.Kod select x.PickUpTime
                                   orderby c.Date
                          select new { kodg = a.Kodg, excursion = b.Name, guide = d.GuideName, data = c.Date, pricead = b.Price, 
                              pricech = b.PriceChd, pax = t.Pax, child = t.Ch, paxleft = GetPax(a.Kodg), pickup = pu.FirstOrDefault()};
            return Ok(result);
        }
```

And here is the function returning needed value:

```
public int GetPax(int id)
        {
            //get pax quota
            var pre = db.Grafik.Where(k => k.Kodg == id).Select(p => p.Quota).SingleOrDefault();
            if (pre.HasValue && pre.Value > 0)
            {
                //Get taken pax
                var p = (from a in db.Orders where a.Kodg == id & !(a.Cansel == true) select a.Child).Sum();
                var c = (from a in db.Orders where a.Kodg == id & !(a.Cansel == true) select a.Pax).Sum();
                if (p.HasValue & c.HasValue)
                {
                    return pre.Value - (p.Value + c.Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    return pre.Value;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately tables Orders and Grafik have no any connection, so I can't use its in the same query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. Ok, this could be a bit strange way, but it's working.

```
public IHttpActionResult GetГрафик(int id)
        {
            xTourist t = db.xTourist.Find(id);
            var beach = db.xAdres.Find(t.Hotel).Kod;
            var result = from a in db.Grafik
                          join b in db.Excursions on a.Excursion equals b.Kod
                          join c in db.Dates on a.Kodd equals c.Kodd      
                          join d in db.Staff on a.Guidename equals d.Kod
                          join e in db.Заказы on a.КодГ equals e.КодГ
                         where c.Дата > t.Датапр && c.Дата < t.Датаотл
                          let pu = from x in db.xPickUp where x.КодП == beach && x.Excursion == b.Kod select x.PickUpTime
                                   orderby c.Дата
                                   let pl = a.Пребукинг - (e.Child + e.Pax)
                          select new { kodg = a.КодГ, excursion = b.Название, guide = d.Name, data = c.Дата, pricead = b.Price, 
                              pricech = b.PriceChd, pax = t.Колчел, child = t.Дети, paxleft = pl, pickup = pu.FirstOrDefault()};
            return Ok(result);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Web API is seeing two public methods with `id` as a parameter and it can't figure out which one to execute when you send your request. Looking at your code, there's no need for the helper method `GetPax()` to be public. Try changing it to private.

```
private int GetPax(int id) // ...
```

Comment: I did changed. But here is another error: Expression LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method "Int32 GetPax (Int32)", so it can not be converted into an expression repository.

Comment: Looks like your initial problem is solved and Web API is able to find the right action to execute. What you're left with now is a problem with your LINQ to Entities expression.

Comment: Yes, that's right. It's not about routing. Anyway, any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: If you must use GetPax(), you'll need to somehow execute the query without calling GetPax(), as Entity Framework doesn't know how to translate it to SQL. Once the query is turned into an IEnumerable (e.g. using `ToList()`), you can use GetPax() as you are now dealing with LINQ to Objects. Looks like this query might be a performance nightmare though.